# Multiple words regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I need to extract multiple words at the same time from more than one text documents. I used regular expression `grep` like

```
b <- grep("sale down",wfr1[x])
```

If I add the second string, the result gives me `zero`. Example:

```
b <- grep("sale down","goes up","goes down slowly",wfr1[x])
```

I want combination of words expression to extract me like above two or three words if it match. Any suggestions?

Here is my corpus or the data file that contains keywords that i want to extract. I want to extraxt the occurance of the keyowrds in the following documents

tech stocks to watch  apple inc aapl nokia corporation nok tesla tsla blackberry bbry
written by mark cooper on january  sale down and stock and goes up
apple inc nasdaqaapls ibeacon tech to be used for fun in ces scavenger hunt apple inc nasdaqaapls stock traded at beginning with a price of  and throughout the trading session climbed at a high of  and later when daytrade ended the stock finally fell  to end at  apple inc nasdaqaapls stock showed weekly performance of goes down and alos goes up for the movement. sale down and goes up. sale down
months after selling its mobile business to microsoft nokia corporation adr nysenok has officially ended support for symbian and meego apps the finnish company has abandoned the two homegrown mobile operating systems in favor of microsofts windows phone nokia corporation adr nysenok yesterday closed at  stock institutional ownership is  in its share capital nokia goes up corporation adr nysenok has  billion outstanding shares among them up billion shares sale down have been floated in market

Comment: Please post an example vector with some strings that are representative for your problem (together with the expected output).

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what your inputs are (text you are matching against vs. patterns to match), and what you expect your outputs to be.  Please show examples of both the text and the patterns you are looking for, as well as for those examples what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 1):

In your question it remains a bit unclear what the pattern is you are searching for. A bit counterintuitively, the pattern is the first argument in `grep`, the string(s) you are processing, the second.

I guess what you want is either to search for the regex pattern in *several strings*. Then you need to pass a vector, not several strings as separate arguments as you do now, e.g. (see `?grep`)

```
> grep("test", "where is test")
[1] 1
> grep("test", c("another test", "where is test"))
[1] 1 2
```

If on the other hand you want to search for one of several strings in a document you need to change the regex, e.g. using the OR operator.

```
> grep("test|nothing", c("just nothing"))
[1] 1
> grep("test|nothing", c("another test or maybe nothing"))
[1] 1
> grep("test|nothing", c("just a test"))
[1] 1
> grep("test|nothing", c("neither tes*  nor nothin*"))
integer(0)
```

Comment: Sir I want more than one string at same time from text documents like articles

Comment: Actually I want ot extract the above words from documents. The words can single or combination for exmaple "sale","sale down"

Comment: example: > grep("sale down", wfr1)
[1] 1 2
> grep("sale down","goes up", wfr1)
integer(0)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for grep states: `If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the ﬁrst element is used with a warning.`

I guess you'll want something like:

`grep("sale down|goes up|goes down slowly", wfr1[x])`

Comment: Sir  it give me below result but I have more then this three result. any guide ? grep("sale down|goes up|goes down slowly", wfr1)
[1] 1 2

Comment: The `|` in the expression is merely an "OR".  I.e., match this OR that.  It can be used to match several things at once, much like you would normally do in separate cases. `grep("sale down", wfr1[x])
grep("goes up", wfr1[x])`, etc.  You never told us what's in `wfr1[x]`, so I'm not sure what to expect.  I'm just trying to help you understand the regular expression. ;)

Comment: Sir wfr1[1] is a folder that I want to parse documents from wfr1[x] folder